# Accessing location field programmatically in Drupal 7, via hosting entity object and wrapper

Tags: entities, location

I'm using Location module (particularly its Location CCK part) with Drupal 7. Added location field 'field_location' to User (as an example of hosting entity), and initialized location values for test users in user edit interface. However, I'm unable to access location data of the current user:

```
global $user;
$user_id = $user->uid;

$loc = $user->field_location;
```

or:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user_id);
$loc = $wrapper->field_location;
```

The statements with $loc don't work for object and wrapper (while both user object and wrapper are initialized successfully). Same for:

```
$loc = $wrapper->field_location[0];
$loc = $wrapper->field_location->raw();
```

I've read a number of posts on this topic, however haven't found a workable solution, would appreciate insights on this.

Answer (score 1):

For a custom field to be available to the wrapper, the module defining it needs to implement [`hook_entity_property_info()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info/7) (or, which is new to me, by adding property metadata to the field using [`hook_field_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_info_alter/7)).

The location_cck module doesn't do that, but the bundled location_entity module does.

If you enable that module you should be able to access the location field as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

What about loading the user?

```
$my_user = user_load($user->uid);
```

Then you should be able to access all fields of the user...

Comment: global $user; should be providing the user object for the currently logged in user.